# border-color ignores my color

Tags: html, css, colors

I would like to use the color `#644220` for the border of my input field. I have tried it like this:

**HTML**

```
<input class="my_border" type="text">
```

**CSS**

```
.my_border {
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 50px;
    border-color: #644220;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dss92v6/1/

When I use `red` or any other HEX code, it will work for me. It won't only accept the code `#644220`. And `#644220` is an existing color as you see [here](http://www.color-hex.com/color/644220).

Not even the RGB code (`border-color: rgb(100, 66, 32);`) is working.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: it works but its `1px` you don't see well

Comment: You set top and right width as 0. `border-width: 0 0 1px 50px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

> Note: The default value of `border-style` is `none`. This means that if
>   you change the `border-width` and the `border-color`, you will not see the
>   border unless you change this property to something other than none or
>   hidden.

Now I assume that browsers are not following this and they show some solid default `border` by default. <sup>[1]</sup>

You need to define a `style` for your `border` for example `solid`

```
border-style: solid;
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9dss92v6/2/)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Was playing further with this, turns out that it's weird behavior I think from the browsers point of view. If am using a word like `red` or `tomato` as color names, it works but still, the color is not the one we expect it to be for example [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9dss92v6/4/) vs [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9dss92v6/5/).

I will update this thread if I got any solid reasoning for this.

---

Edit 3:

Debugging further, it turns out that the default value Chrome sets is `inset` for `border`, i.e, `border-style: inset;`, which has grayish border which is like a shadow. Hence, your `color` does render but it mixes with the `inset` border being set by Chrome defaults. Now am not sure why the color is not overridden by the `color` declaration you have in your stylesheet, might be a bug.

Comment: Still wondering why it is working for any other color. But thanks, that really resolved the problem!

Comment: @Reza Well it's not, Read the details after the demo link, I am still thinking why it's working in a weird way.

Comment: @Reza: It's not works for other color.  Try with `border-width: 5px 10px 20px 50px;` to show more details.

Answer (score 2):

Add `border-style` for it:

```
.my_border {
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 50px;
    border-color: #644220;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to combine the properties of your border in one line like this:

```
.my_border {
    width:100%;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: 10px solid #644220;
}
```

You can always change the thickness of the border. I made it in `10px` so it will be visible.